# Execute constructor code automatically in dylib

Tags: ios, dylib

From what I read, code in the constructor is executed automatically when the library is loaded using dlopen.

How can I do this for a Framework for iOS? I want the dylib to run some code in the constructor when it is loaded.

In Apple's documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/100-Articles/CreatingDynamicLibraries.html), I saw this snippet

```
// Initializer.
__attribute__((constructor))
static void initializer(void) {                             // 2
    printf("[%s] initializer()\n", __FILE__);
}
 
// Finalizer.
__attribute__((destructor))
static void finalizer(void) {                               // 3
    printf("[%s] finalizer()\n", __FILE__);
}
```

I have tried the following

- I created an Xcode Project for a Framework. In the Framework, I added the above code snippet. Then I build a debug version of the Framework.

What I want to do is

- Modify a user's bitcode file (extracted from a bitcode enabled IPA) to merge some of my own code into it. My code (written in C and converted to bitcode for merging) would call dlopen on the dylib and when it is loaded, the constructor code will execute.

Comment: Frameworks _are_ dylibs. Constructors work the exact same way. But I think you have some severe misconceptions about bitcode. For one, bitcode is just an intermediate format that still has to be compiled down to actual machine code before it's executable. A bitcode-enabled IPA just allows Apple to do that without involvement of the original developer. But for another, you cannot modify code at runtime in (unjailbroken) iOS. AMFI.kext will straight-up SIGKILL you.

Comment: Hi @Siguza

Thanks for the reply. If I understand correctly, what you meant was all the code that I want executed has to be in the binary itself during compilation and I cannot load additional code during runtime that alters the behaviour of the application?